# Retrofit: turn all parameters to encrypt String before urlEncode

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

guys.Recently,I have a problem.I am using Retrofit + okhttp to do the network. But now I have to encrypt all the parameters,since I have Chinese in the parameters,it will be encoded before interceptor,so for those apis,i have to do something special。I think it's not a good idea,.so is there any solution to encrypt the parameters before it's been encoded?

Comment: simple, before you pass the value to the api factory where you call the post method,just encrypt from there. There is no middle ware encryption strategies. If so then that contradicts the nature of encryption. What library you plan on using for encrypting your data before transmitting it?

Comment: we do the encryption ourself. now I do the encrypt in the interceptor. so if I pass the encryied string into api, I still need to do some special to skip this api. I find that Retrofit.Builder.callFactory maybe can create a newCall from the orginal call ,in here maybe i can do the encrpt,but I don't know how to crate a Factory's instance while still use the orignal okhttpclient.Beacuse i don'e think i can write another httpClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by creating a new Call to replace the orginal one like below. hope to help some one like me.

```
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = CustomHeaderOkHttpClient.newInstance()
                .newBuilder()
                .build();
        Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitUtils.createGsonRxJavaRetrofitBuilder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .callFactory(new Call.Factory() {
                    @Override
                    public Call newCall(Request request) {
                        Request encryptRequest = EncryptCallHelper.encryptRequest(request);
                        return okHttpClient.newCall(encryptRequest);
                    }
                })
                .baseUrl(sBaseUrl)
                .build();
```

Comment: what is `EncryptCallHelper`

Comment: long time no come,sorry.   EncryptCallHelper is the helper method to encrypt my request params

Comment: what is  CustomHeaderOkHttpClient

Comment: It's a OkhttpClient with some cutome Interceptors to add headers & some usual settings

Comment: can you please provide EncryptCallHelper and CustomHeaderOkHttpClient for reference

Comment: plz see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

CustomHeaderOkHttpClient is just an instance of OkHttp like blow.

```
public class CustomHeaderOkHttpClient {

    public static OkHttpClient.Builder newBaseBuilder(Context context) {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .cookieJar(new WebViewCookieJar())
               ;
    }
}
```

the EncryptCallHelper I cannot paste here ,I am so sorry. the content works like this:

1. get all params with the request
2. encrypt your params in your own way
3. return the new Call to Retrofit